# Include information at the beginning of a document based on what comes later

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I need to show a list of items/keywords/duedates used throughout my document at the beginning of the document, and make them hyperlinks. To be able to use this information the beginning of the document, I'm (ab)using a ToC-like structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\listofduereviews{\textbf{Due Dates:}~\@starttoc{due}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\duedate}[1]{%
    \hypertarget{link.#1}{#1}%
    \addtocontents{due}{\protect\hyperlink{link.#1}{(#1)}\quad}%
    }

\begin{document}
\listofduereviews
\bigskip

The first due date is \duedate{01-May-2012}, and the second due date is \duedate{02-May-2012}.
\end{document}
```

This does what I want:

[image]

But I feel I'm abusing ToCs for what they are not made for (or maybe I'm not, I just don't have enough LaTeX literacy to judge myself). What is a more elegant way to achieve this? Perhaps writing directly to a (non-listof) file?

Comment: I don't see what's unelegant about using `\@starttoc`; after all this LaTeX commands internally writes information to an external file (which seems to be what you are asking for in your final comment).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, well, that's good news then! Basically, I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: You may care to take a look at the `tocloft` package (or `memoir`, which includes its functionality). This would allow you to set up a separate space for due dates, leaving the table of contents functionality intact and independent. I'm sorry, but at the moment I have neither the time nor the experience to make this into a good answer.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough what `tocloft`'s `\newlistof` command does behind the scenes is to use `\@starttoc` in a similar manner to what **Ali Mehrzi** is already doing, so I don't really see the point of using `tocloft` here. And since **Ali Mehrzi**'s code writes a file with extension `.due`, its code leaves `.toc` untouched, so the ToC functionality reamins intact and independent.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, I admit it's a marginal change, but I thought OP might want to avoid \makeatletter and other pieces of LaTeX mysticism... :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Essentially what I'm asking for is better ways (if any) of writing to an external file without having to resort to the ToC mechanism.

Comment: @AliMehrizi I sense some confusion here; the name of the command is `\@starttoc`, but once you provide an extension other than `toc` as the argument, this has nothing to do with the actual ToC. Of course, instead of using `\@starttoc` you could set the things yourself (using `\@input` and `\newwrite` and `\openout`...) but `\@starttoc` internally does exactly this job for you so I think your approach is perfectly valid.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, yes, I'm aware that I'm not really adding anything to my actual ToC (hence "listof" in my original post). I just wanted to make sure I'm not abusing anything in LaTeX. The second sentence in your comment above actually answers my question. Would you please just add that to your answer below (the same sentence verbatim would work) and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AliMehrizi I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything unelegant about using `\@starttoc`; after all this LaTeX command internally writes information to an external file (which seems to be what you are asking for in your final comment).

Of course, instead of using `\@starttoc` you could set the things yourself (using `\@input`, `\newwrite`, `\openout`...) but `\@starttoc` internally does exactly this job for you so I think your approach is perfectly valid.